# Put a TextView in front of a ImageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im searching a way how to fix a TextView on a ,for example, transparent square like in the Picture I did in Paint.net .So the TextView should in front of the transparent square (ImageView).Also it should stretch when the screen is bigger.

http://www7.pic-upload.de/22.02.14/24vtze5ulxc2.png

How can I solve the problem ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/semi_transparent_background"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This is my text."/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Alternatively, you could do something similar with a relative layout.

Comment: Okay and how can I make it stretchy ? So If the Screen is bigger that the TextView is still in the Imageview (Square in this example ) ?

Comment: In this case, since the TextView and ImageView fill the FrameLayout, it will stretch accordingly.  If this is not what you mean, could you explain a little further?

Comment: I dont know how to explain it so I made a second example in paint.net http://www7.pic-upload.de/22.02.14/gyo2w9p1g433.png

Comment: The TextView will always have the same size as the ImageView.  You'll need to ensure the FrameLayout doesn't fill the screen, however, in order to achieve the effect you want.  I've update the width/height in my answer above to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You can use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout for that.

```
<FrameLayout>
   <ImageView>
   <TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Your textview will appear on ImageView.

Although note that, RelativeLayout has double taxation tradeoff. Each measure and layout happens twice.

Answer (score 3):

Simply ordering the items in RelativeLayout from top to bottom in the XML will make each in turn move to the front compared to the others above it.